# Simple home router routing

Tags: networking, router, routing

Having simple home modem/router i have no option to view and edit the routing table (the configuration is WEB-page type). Moreover there is an option "RIP support" which is disabled by default.

1. Does it mean that the routing table is build statically (without interacting with other routers).
2. If I'm right that the routing table is modified automatically when the network topology changes (for e.g. a new route added when connecting a new host to the router port)?
3. Is there any way to view the table?

Comment: A typical home network is basically going to be a "stub network." It is a single isolated network with one way in and one way out, so most of SOHO routers are all going to have minimal routing tables as Darren describes in his answer. For the typical home network, there is rarely ever a reason to have anything more complex.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine your routing table is going to be very simple and look like this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         <gw address removed> 0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
<ip address removed>     *               255.255.252.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.10.0    *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 br0
```

(excuse the formatting)

That is; a default route pointing to your ISP's gateway device, a route for your ISP's network out of one interface and a route for your local LAN out of the other one. There's not going to be any requirement to dynamically build a routing table because everything not destined for the LAN will be sent to your ISP's gateway. The routing table will be built based on the network interface configurations or DHCP.

It's impossible to say if you can view the routing table as you don't provide a make or model.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort of, a default gateway is provided by DHCP from the ISP. That is injected as a static route in the routing table by the DHCP client process.
2. For individual hosts, it will not add an additional entry to the routing table. Routes are for L3 subnets, not for L2 ARP entries.
3. This is higly dependant on the router/firmware. Check the manual. Sometimes these things can be polled with SNMP, if you're lucky you could find a routing table at SNMP OID .1.3.6.1.2.1.4.21 (see [RFC1213-MIB](http://www.oidview.com/mibs/0/RFC1213-MIB.html))

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the connectivity provided by your ISP, your router receives certain IP configuration for its WAN port (ip address, netmask, gateway address, dns servers, the ip address is probably a public one).

What your router does is get the packets it receives from hosts connected to its Ethernet ports (or via WiFi) and sends them over to it's WAN Gateway (which is a default gateway, or gateway of last resort).

RIP is a distance vector routing protocol, which serves as communication protocol between two routers - to exchange information for the routes they know and they have in their routing tables (if they are configured in that way, of course). In order your home router to work with RIP, it needs to be configured to communicate with other RIP enabled routers - you just can't have it use RIP by itself.

To answer your questions:

1. depending on the router you have you might be able to add static
   routes by yourself. In most cases, a SOHO (small office/home office)
   device will route and/or NAT traffic from Ethernet ports to WAN
   ports.
2. that depends on the settings and on the router model, but usually
   when you connect a device to the router's Ethernet port, the DHCP
   service running on the router sends an IP configuration to the newly
   connected hosts - that's all that happens
3. That again depends on the router model